# rails nested resources handle edit path as id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have the following routes

```
resources :users, path: '/' do
   resources :posts, path: '/'
end
```

the problem is that the inner route override the outer route for user's edit path.

http://localhost/user/edit refer to posts#show instead users#edit

EDIT

Singular resource is not the solution, I want to access the user via his ID.

lets say I have user with id "Jo" and post with id "My-First-Post", then the corresponding route should be http://localhost/Jo/My-First-Post. that's work just fine with my current solution.

the problem is that when I access /Jo/edit I get exception that there is no post with id "edit" while I want this route to refer to Jo's edit page (users#edit)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? It sort of looks like you want a singular resource. If that's the case, you can just do:

routes.rb

```
resource :user
```

So just make the word `resource` and `user` singular. Then you'll get singular routes, like `user/edit`.

See the Rails guide for more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources